# T-test and importing data from columns

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, probability, t-test

I am trying to conduct a T-test on two unequal samples using the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

UG = pd.read_csv('Mostfrequentscores.csv')
print('Mean', UG['Iceland'].mean())
print('Mean', UG['Peru'].mean())

I = UG['Iceland']
P = UG['Peru']

t = stats.ttest_ind(I, P, equal_var = False)
```

The mean prints fine, which I assume means its reading the columns in the file - but the T-test keeps on giving me the following error:

> C:\Users\msu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_distn_infrastructure.py:879:
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater

Could this be due to my data which is a series of numbers from -3 to 3? Do I need to convert it using float?

Comment: Have you checked if `I` or `P` contain nan values ?

Comment: Thans for the reply Yes I did. Just negative, positive and 0 values.

Comment: can you tell us what happens if you do convert to float? (would there be some zero integer mean used to divide and get variance or something?)

Comment: I get the same error. i tried the following for the one column:                           
       Per = UG['peru'].astype(float)

Comment: You will have to post some of your data, otherwise it is hard to help.